# Why do I run into this error when creating a Delphi embedded FAST Report 4.0 (using user defined variables and FAST conditional functions)

Tags: variables, delphi, crystal-reports, conditional-formatting, fastreport

I am trying to create a new `Fast Report 4.0` embedded report from scratch due to previously supported `SAP Crystal reports` being deprecated.

Why don't conditional functions seem to ever work with user made variables or even with query defined fields? In my masterdata I have a memo field for troubleshooting

```
[IIF(1 = 1, query1."field1", 0)]
```

the brackets should let the `IIF` be evaluated and always return me my field1 but the report breaks with the error:

> The following error(s) have occured: Memo29: Error in expression
> 'IIF(1 =1, query1."field1", 0)': ')' expected»

This doesn't work so of course neither does something like

```
[IIF(query1."data1"> = <PrevYear>, <s1query1."NET">,0)]
```

where  is my variable in my 'Report Variables' folder that is set to 1 for example. What am I doing so terribly wrong, it seemes that I'm obviously not missing any parentheses nor am I forgetting the brackets..
Please don't newbiebomb me, I have genuinely looked into everything and anything for a solution, attempted using the Fast report's own forum to no avail (I get an error when trying to post as an anonymous user or even when attempting to sign up)..

[Tried using the conditional functions in text memos as described in the documentation and Fast report forums

e.g.:

```
[(IIF 1=1, myquery."myfield", myquery."myOtherField")]
```

this doesn't work]

Comment: Would be easier to follow if you used some formatting and layout to separate things a bit - like expressions marked as code and an explanation paragraph separate from the specific expressions you are having problems with.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, for my implementation of Fast Report, the equality comparator in FAST functions is not `=` as noted in the documentation and mentioned in the Fast Report Forums but rather `==`
so

```
[IIF(1=1,1,0)]
```

doesn't work but

```
[IIF(1==1,1,0)]
```

works..

Answer (score 0):

I only see that error if there is an extra comma in the IIF part of the expression. The expression below works fine in a memo dropped on a report here and shows up as `Test2` in report preview.

```
[IIF(FALSE,'Test','Test2')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, this should work when used inside the MasterDatat too, in my case it really doesn't. I just copied and pasted your example and this doesn't work at all what could be going so wrong.

Comment: It works fine in a MasterData band. "Doesn't work at all" is not very descriptive.

Comment: I meant to say it throws the exact same error as my example function «The following error(s) have occured: Memo29: Error in expression 'IIF(1 =1, query1."field1", 0)': ')' expected»